# yahoo api for contact import query returns only 10 datas

Tags: php, api, yahoo

i am using yahoo api for importing contact into my php website.
I use the query:

```
 $query = sprintf("SELECT * from social.contacts WHERE guid=me");
 $response = $yahoo->query($query);
```

but the issue is that it returns only 10 datas where as i have 11.
more over i tried to go to their developer console: 
    [http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+social.contacts+where+guid%3Dme](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+%2a+from+social.contacts+where+guid=me)
 and tried out the query but is still returns 10 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html

**Quote**

> The maximum number of items returned by a `SELECT` is 5000. The maximum processing time for a YQL statement is 30 seconds. For most tables, the default number of items returned is 10. (That is, the default is 10 if you do not specify a limit in the `SELECT` statement.)

So 10 results is a default behaviour, if you want more, specify another `limit` value.

Comment: thanks for the answer.I changed my query to:SELECT * from social.contacts(0) WHERE guid=me. but still it returns 10 items.

Comment: i am still getting 10

Comment: and this `SELECT * from social.contacts(20) WHERE guid=me` ?